# slider in tableview full demo

Tags: slider, tableview

for CustomeTableViewCell.h

```
//
//  CustomeTableViewCell.h
//  Slider Program
//
//  Created by Naeem Shaikh on 21/08/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 KIintu Designs Pvt. Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol SliderDelegate<NSObject>
- (void)sliderChanged:(id)self;
@end

@interface CustomeTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myCellLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SliderDelegate>sliderDelegate;


- (IBAction)sliderValuechanged:(UISlider *)sender;

@end
```

for CustomeTableViewCell.m

```
//
//  CustomeTableViewCell.m
//  Slider Program
//
//  Created by Naeem Shaikh on 21/08/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 KIintu Designs Pvt. Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CustomeTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomeTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (IBAction)sliderValuechanged:(UISlider *)sender {

    self.myCellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(NSInteger)sender.value];
    //call the custom delegate each time when slider is slided
    if([_sliderDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sliderChanged:)])
    {
        [_sliderDelegate sliderChanged:self]; //passing the entire cell itself
    }
}
@end
```

for viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomeTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate>{
    //NSArray *tableList;
    UITableView *mytableview;
    int SliderChangeValue;

}

@property (strong , nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *tableDemo;
@property (strong , nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrSlider;
@property (strong,  nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *sliderDicValues;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;//add outlet to tableview

@end
```

for viewcontroller.m

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Slider Program
//
//  Created by Naeem Shaikh on 21/08/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 KIintu Designs Pvt. Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize arrSlider;
@synthesize sliderDicValues;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //    tableList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    //                 @"Cell 1",@"Cell 2",@"Cell 3",@"Cell 4",@"Cell 5",
    //                 @"Cell 6",@"Cell 7",@"Cell 8",@"Cell 9",@"Cell 10",
    //                 @"Cell 11",@"Cell 12",@"Cell 13",@"Cell 14",@"Cell 15",
    //                 @"Cell 16",@"Cell 17",@"Cell 18",@"Cell 19",@"Cell 20",
    //                 nil];

    arrSlider = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    sliderDicValues = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    //[mytableview registerClass:[CustomeTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    //[tableList count]

    return 50;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableCell = @"Cell";
    CustomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableCell];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomeTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableCell];
    }
    if([self.sliderDicValues objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]]) //check if there is any slided value is present
    {
        NSNumber *value = [self.sliderDicValues objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
        [cell.mySlider setValue:value.integerValue]; //set the slider value
        [cell.myCellLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value.integerValue]];//and also label
    }
    else //set to default values
    {
        [cell.mySlider setValue:(NSInteger)0];
        [cell.myCellLabel setText:@"label"];
    }
    //add a single target don't add double target to slider
    cell.sliderDelegate = self;//set the delegate
    return cell;
}

- (void)sliderChanged:(CustomeTableViewCell *)cell
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [_myTableView indexPathForCell:cell]; //get the indexpath
    if(path)//check if valid path
    {
        SliderChangeValue = cell.mySlider.value;
        [self.sliderDicValues setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:SliderChangeValue] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",path.row]]; //set the value in the dictionary later used in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method
    }
    //     SliderChangeValue = (int)sender.value;
    NSLog(@"%d",SliderChangeValue);
}


//dont use it
-(void)customSliderValue:(UISlider *)sender{

    //    NSString *value =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d" ,(int)sender.value];
    //    NSString *tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)sender.tag];
    //
    //    NSLog(@"%@ %@",value , tag);
    //
    //    [self.dicSilder setObject:value forKey:@"value"];
    //    [self.dicSilder setObject:tag forKey:@"tag"];
    //
    //    [self.arrSlider addObject:self.dicSilder];
    //    NSLog(@"%@",self.arrSlider);


    SliderChangeValue = (int)sender.value;

    NSLog(@"%d",SliderChangeValue);

}

//this is also put a delegate from the cell like slider , just add the another method in the protocol and perform action, if u don't get just comment i will update the code and u hav t modify this method according to your requirement
-(void)customeBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *value =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d" ,SliderChangeValue];
    NSString *tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sender.tag];

    //NSLog(@"%@ %@",value,tag);
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dic setObject:value forKey:@"value"];
    [dic setObject:tag forKey:@"tag"];

    //NSLog(@"%@",dic);

    [arrSlider addObject:dic];


    NSLog(@"%@",arrSlider);

    NSString *sliderTagAtIndexPath = @"";
    //NSString *sliderValueAtindexPath = @"";

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSlider.count; i++) {

        NSString *strTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrSlider objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"tag"]];

        if([strTag isEqualToString:tag])
        {
            //NSString *strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrSlider objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"value"]];

            sliderTagAtIndexPath = strTag;
            //sliderValueAtindexPath = strValue;
        }
    }
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Clicked"
                                                         message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell : %@ Value: %d", sliderTagAtIndexPath ,SliderChangeValue]
                                //message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell : %@ Value: %@", sliderTagAtIndexPath ,sliderValueAtindexPath]
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [myAlertView show];

}
@end
```

here is the link for whole app

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/1d4ktomjytb818l,8zcg0zbymee57z8/shared

it is demo for slider in tableview with solution.

Comment: And... what is your question?

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/vd8v3f2jkyo113g,8zcg0zbymee57z8,1d4ktomjytb818l/shared

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/ya9e3i16s2x9od1,vd8v3f2jkyo113g,8zcg0zbymee57z8,1d4ktomjytb818l/shared

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/nc3oa38w93jnd33,ya9e3i16s2x9od1,vd8v3f2jkyo113g,8zcg0zbymee57z8,1d4ktomjytb818l/shared